# Certificate verify failed Heroku Ruby on Rails 3.2.1 Ruby 1.9.2p290

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, certificate

In heroku logs :

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `block in connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:678:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:637:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:626:in `start'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/client.rb:409:in `read_logs'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/logs.rb:31:in `index'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:135:in `run'
    from /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/bin/heroku:30:in `<main>'
```

I haven't the foggiest idea what to do here. Using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.2.1 on Ubuntu 11.10. Have tried updating my certificate to latest from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/151157/ubuntu-10-04-curl-how-do-i-fix-update-the-ca-bundle) but it did not seem to make a difference.

Also tried adding the following code from [here](http://jimneath.org/2011/10/19/ruby-ssl-certificate-verify-failed.html) and pushing back to heroku but that did not work either.

Comment: This helped me - http://stackoverflow.com/a/16983443/11792

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been posted as an issue on Heroku's github account.  They are working on it and have a quick fix:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/245

Comment: Yeah, glad to see I wasn't the only one annoyed with this last night.

Answer (score 2):

I hit the same.

I did the following to resolve:

```
~ $ heroku version
2.21.1
~ $ gem uninstall heroku --version 2.21.1
Successfully uninstalled heroku-2.21.1
~ $ heroku version
heroku-gem/2.20.1
~ $ heroku logs --app myapp
2012-03-02T04:12:22+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 24.4.137.156 - - [02/Mar/2012:04:12:22 +0000] "GET /assets/layout/nav_bar-0fecc02...
```

Comment: rather than downgrading, they appear to be working on the issue but see my answer below as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
[sudo] gem install certified
```

add to gemfile : `gem 'certified'`

```
bundle install
```

added `/certs` to `/lib` from https://github.com/stevegraham/certified to be sure