# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, openssl, omniauth

I'm trying to authenticate a user via Facebook or Twitter, get them to fill out their information, and then click save (thus creating a user record). I'm getting an OpenSSL error on that final step -- after clicking save. This happens at the Devise RegistrationsController#create method.

So I'm getting this error in my Rails application, hosted on Heroku:

```
2012-07-28T18:25:13+00:00 app[web.1]: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed)
```

I've seen plenty of solutions, none of them work. Here are some things I've tried:

1) Installing the `certified` gem

2) Upgrading the Heroku gem to v2.30, pushing again

3) This:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET, {:client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => "/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"}}}
  provider :facebook, FACEBOOK_KEY, FACEBOOK_SECRET, {:scope => "publish_actions,user_location,email", :client_options => {:ssl => {:ca_file => "/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"}}}
end
```

It seems like one problem could be that this cert file doesn't actually exist -- I've seen it in several places, and it seems like that is the default path to the ca_cert file for Heroku, but I could be wrong.

Oddly enough, this is happening *after* I've already authenticated via FB/Twitter, and am trying to create a user's account. Why would this be, and how can I solve/debug this? Sincerely confused.

**Update:** I added this line to the Omniauth initializer, and now it "works". Thus I've diagnosed the problem is with Omniauth. However, I'd like to still have the SSL verification... this obviously leaves a security gap.

`OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`

Comment: take a look at my answer below. It still keeps the verification.

Comment: @Simone Carletti marked this question as duplicate, but it is not. The other question is about problems to update Ruby Gems and this one is for not being able to call 3rd party https:// services from Heroku.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

After some searching here is what I found:

If you’re using Ruby to open connections to an external server over https, eg. the Facebook Graph API, you may run into the following error:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError:SSL_connectreturned=1errno=0state=SSLv3readservercertificateB:certificateverifyfailed
```

This error is due to Ruby not being able to find the certification authority certificates (CA Certs) used to verify the authenticity of secured web servers. The solution is to download the this [ca-bundle.crt](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/ca-bundle.crt) into your application’s `lib/` directory:
Then add the following code to `config/initializers/fix_ssl.rb`:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/https'

module Net
  class HTTP
    alias_method :original_use_ssl=, :use_ssl=

    def use_ssl=(flag)
      self.ca_file = Rails.root.join('lib/ca-bundle.crt').to_s
      self.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
      self.original_use_ssl = flag
    end
  end
end
```

This should force ruby to use the CA bundle from your application’s lib/ directory.

Taken from: http://jimneath.org/2011/10/19/ruby-ssl-certificate-verify-failed.html

**UPDATE:**

You may need to use `self.ca_path=` instead of `self.ca_file=` depending on your system.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. How is the .crt file kept up to date?

Comment: You have to keep it up to date manually. If you are hosting on Heroku  I think you can use their CA file `/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

Comment: Worked for me on Heroku using /usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt - thanks!

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 7 using the exact code posted.

Comment: @nicola-peluchetti when you say you got this to work on Windows 7, where exactly did you find the file in question? Or did you create it? If so, if which location? Thanks!

Comment: @GaryEwanPark as th OP said, copy the certificate in the `/lib` folder and create the ruby file in `config/initializers`. Restert the server obviously.

Comment: @nicola-peluchetti That is the thing, in my installation of Ruby, (which was done using Chocolatey, and not RubyInstaller) I don't have a ```config/initializers``` folder, so I was looking for some help on where, in my installation, I can implement this solution. Thanks!

Comment: @GaryEwanPark this solution is for Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I just started getting this error on Heroku - nothing has changed in my app... I tried Pavel's solution with self.ca_path and self.ca_file  and the hardwired path to the certs - did not work for me. I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.12. The OpenSSL version is OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009. Any other ideas?

Comment: @craic.com are you using the path to Heroku CA certificates `/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`?

Comment: If hosting on heorku, how are we referencing path?  `self.ca_file = Rails.root.join('/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt').to_s`

Comment: @DaynaJuliana no need to use `Rails.root` here since this is an absolute file path not relative to the root of the project.

Comment: @PavelNikolov this solution doesn't work anymore...I had a recent Windows update on both my laptop and desktop. Tried both `self.ca_path=` and `self.ca_file`.

Comment: @KaMok The provided answer is not tested on Windows, only on Linux. Unfortunately, I do not have a Windows machine where I can test : (

Comment: On heroku, I tried all the variations mentioned and still have no luck. The things I tried were replacing `lib/ca-bundle.crt` with `/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`, and using `ca_path` and `ca_file`, but nothing seems to work. I had never had this error before - it arose somewhat randomly. I will use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33669869/5783745) solution as an imperfect work around for now.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you've got the right openssl configuration in OmniAuth, but perhaps your CA certs path isn't correct?

You can check that on your heroku servers by running:

```
heroku run bash
```

... and then running openssl to display the proper path:

```
$ openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

... You should find the ca_certificates.crt file at $OPENSSLDIR/certs/ca-certificates.crt

I would confirm that path an update your code to match.

Comment: Yup ca-certificates is there... (in `/usr/lib/ssl/certs`). Thanks for `heroku run bash`.. didn't know about that

Comment: Is this something that Omniauth requires, or every external request? Maybe that's the problem... I'm making another external request that isn't working?

Comment: Yeah, can you provide more context from your logs about where it's throwing the SSL error?  Perhaps a stack trace?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all it gave me so far, I'll try to set the debug level higher and let you know. But also, check the update -- it's sort of helpful.