# OpenSSL error using Active Merchant for Moneris

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, heroku, https

My production app uses ActiveMerchant and is unable to process credit cards over https with a single gateway, Moneris. All other gateways Authorize.net, Paypal, Beanstream, etc) experience no errors. The error I receive is:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed):
```

The people at Moneris have told me that they have updated their SSL certificate
 to 2048bit SSL encryption (from the current 1024 SSL encryption)  and that the upgraded certificate will be issued by VeriSign. Our wildcard SSL uses 2432--more than the Moneris 2047 requirement.

So, they suggested that in addition to the files I normally upload for my SSL bundle, I have to add their Verisign certs.  My Heroku command looks like this:

```
$ heroku certs:upgrade --app myapp AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt ComodoUTNSGCCA.crt EssentialSSLCA_2.crt STAR_myapp_com.crt UTNAddTrustSGCCA.crt Verisign_chain_Gr.cer Verisign_G5.cer server.key
```

I have tried virtually everything including the fix_ssl.rb suggestion here ([OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703679/opensslsslsslerror-on-heroku/16983443#16983443)) where I call the ca-certificates.crt from my /usr/lib/ssl/certs directory from Heroku.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/https'

module Net
  class HTTP
    alias_method :original_use_ssl=, :use_ssl=
    def use_ssl=(flag)
      self.ca_path = Rails.root.join('/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt').to_s
      self.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
      self.original_use_ssl = flag
    end
  end
end
```

I've tried everything: placing the Heroku bundle in my /lib directory, adding the 'certified' gem, etc, etc. and spent hours on the phone with Moneris to no avail.  Does anyone know what more I can do to allow this one gateway to process credit cards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the trusted list of CA certificates that openssl is using to verify Moneris' server certificate is out-dated. So try getting the cacert.pem extracted from Mozilla's ca-bundle (http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html does this for you). This is more necessary these days as far as openssl is concerned as openssl is no longer bundled with CA certs which is why I'm suspecting whatever ca-certs you're using might be out of date.

First I tried to reproduce your problem with the command:

openssl s_client -connect www3.moneris.com:443

and got ...

```
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-MD5
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : RC4-MD5
    Session-ID: 73178D4019035AE86399D0E6D2FFB904A1412D0F5D3F83370E52F50E9E26B73C
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 0BB841912F11185B7CBAFA524571765DD7372990819EBC44E311DE4EF0C70E480501D6F87C8AA439C4F827B0908123F7
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1380816775
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

Then I used the cacert.pem extracted from Mozilla thanks to http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
and re-issued the openssl command like so:

openssl s_client -connect www3.moneris.com:443 -CAfile cacert.pem

and got ...

```
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is RC4-MD5
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : RC4-MD5
    Session-ID: 73178D401902F7EB6399D0E6D2FFB804CE0F7219344405EA0E52F50E9E26B4DB
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: C0B32810FB7E0158A156E7D05DBB35F3CE8935284F165C3FB636700EEEC8BCE991BCE8850D39020E298F337B6E58132A
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1380816992
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

So in your code snippet, above, try replacing:

```
self.ca_path = Rails.root.join('/usr/lib/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt').to_s
```

with:

```
self.ca_file = <full path name>/cacert.pem
```

where cacert.pem is extracted from the Mozilla ca-bundle