# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect error on Ruby 2.2.1

Tags: ruby, macos, ssl

Here's the code to run:

```
require "net/http"

uri = URI.parse("https://www.google.com")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)
```

I got two version of `irb` in my Mac OSX. One comes default with system. The other is installed later on through rvm.

- /usr/bin/irb (ruby 2.0.0p481)
- /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb (ruby 2.2.1p85)

When using older irb, run above code, it gives me:

`#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>`

When using newer irb, run above code, it gives me:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:74:in `timeout'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
    from (irb):7
    from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

It should be the issue of SSL is not recognized by new version of ruby. Tried [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703679/opensslsslsslerror-on-heroku/16983443#16983443) on StackOverflow but none of them seems fix the problem.

Comment: Look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528101/ssl-connect-returned-1-errno-0-state-sslv3-read-server-certificate-b-certificat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrade my OSX to El Capitan, I reinstall Ruby 2.2.3 through rvm, and it works.