# RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest-client

I send a post request to url to get the access token.

```
result = RestClient.post('https://stackexchange.com/oauth/access_token',
                        {:client_id => CLIENT_ID,
                         :client_secret => CLIENT_SECRET,
                         :code => session_code,
                         :redirect_uri => 'http://rails.example.com:3000/stackoverflow/callback'},
                         #:verify_ssl => false,
                         )
```

but the error as below:

```
RestClient::SSLCertificateNotVerified in StackoverflowController#callback
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

even I set the `verify_ssl` to false, still doesn't work, hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

```
ruby version: ruby 2.2.2p95
rails version: Rails 4.2.3
rest-client (1.8.0)
```

Comment: @WandMaker but my ruby version is 2.2.2

Comment: But I think resolution will be same. This issue keeps getting reported very often.  See this one - which was asked 2 days ago, but no reply for it yet - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32321703/opensslsslsslerror-ssl-connect-error-on-ruby-2-2-1#comment52553498_32321703    Also, add OS details, it may help for people to assist you better

Comment: @WandMaker thanks for your info