# SSL Error with the latest RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

## Attempt #1

I was following [this page](https://rvm.io/support/fixing-broken-ssl-certificates) to fix the OpenSSL Certificate error in my Mac El Capitan.

Though the RVM and certificates are upto date, the certificate error still occurs:

```
☁  ~  rvm -v
rvm 1.26.11 (master) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

☁  ~  rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
Certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.
Certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Up to date.

☁  ~  ruby -e "require 'open-uri'; open 'https://www.google.com'"
/Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:73:in `timeout'
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:318:in `open_http'
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:736:in `buffer_open'
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:211:in `block in open_loop'
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:209:in `catch'
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:209:in `open_loop'
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:150:in `open_uri'
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:716:in `open'
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

## Attempt #2

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16983443/184184).

Create a new file `fix_ssl.rb` in your application initializer with:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/https'

module Net
  class HTTP
    alias_method :original_use_ssl=, :use_ssl=

    def use_ssl=(flag)
      self.ca_file = Rails.root.join('lib/ca-bundle.crt').to_s
      self.ca_path = Rails.root.join('lib/ca-bundle.crt').to_s
      self.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
      self.original_use_ssl = flag
    end
  end
end
```

Download the crt file and place in your lib directory.

Now try the same in rails console:

```
☁  duggout [master] ⚡ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.5)
2.2.3 :001 > require 'open-uri'; open 'https://www.google.com'
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
    from /Users/leninrajrajasekaran/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
```

## OpenSSL

OpenSSL is the one from Homebrew and is latest:

```
☁  ~   openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: clang -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -fno-common -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB_SHARED -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/etc/openssl"
```

How do we fix the certificate error?

Comment: @sawa added the question

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

Upgraded to 2.3.0 ruby with `--disable-binary`

```
rvm uninstall ruby-2.2.3
rvm install ruby-2.3.0 --disable-binary
gem pristine --all
```

And now works:

```
2.3.0 :001 > require 'open-uri'; open 'https://www.google.com'
 => #<Tempfile:/var/folders/xq/lb_rp7gs3_b0_dh8zt5nrbm40000gp/T/open-uri20160326-38471-1xf48xn>
```